# Underlined Adobe Illustrator layers

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, transparency

When you create an opacity mask, the layer with the mask gets underlined in the layers panel. Some of my layers have solid lines and some are dashed. What causes the difference between these two?

[image]

Comment: I have edited the original post with a screenshot from two line datasets that have clipping masks made the same way with a mapping plug-in, yet one is dashed and one is solid. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Solid underline indicates a clipping mask, and dotted underline indicates a transparency (AKA "opacity") mask.

Clipping masks can be made in the layers panel, whereas transparency masks are made in the transparency panel.